# "claims/promotes/pretends"?

Tags: word-choice

Which one is better to convey sense of deception?

> Those who are against Plato for expelling poets from his Utopia should review this poet's life to realize how a poet **claims/promotes/pretends** to be enlightened while he covers up his sick thoughts under his elegant language.

Answer (score 1):

*Promote X* doesn't work if X is an infinitive (not to be confused with *promote to X* if X is a *noun* identifying a rank).

*X pretends to be Y* means X knows he/she/it isn't really Y.

*X claims to be Y* doesn't imply deception - someone can make a claim and be unknowingly wrong, but not be deceptive about it.

You probably want to say *pretends*.